# Create a nested dictionary from a dictionary based on repeated values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to Python (3.6) and I'm trying to figure out a way to create a nested dictionary from a list of lists. The example input is:

```
myList = [[1, B, C],[1, D, C],[1, E, C],[1, F, G],[1, H, G],[2, I, C],[2, J, C],[2, K, G]]
```

What I want to get is:

```
result = {1: {C: [B, D, E], G: [F, H]}, 2: {C: [I, J], G: [K]}}
```

What I've got for now is:

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for key, *values in myList:
    result[key].extend(values)
```

Which gives me the output:

```
{1: [B, C, D, C, E, C, F, G, H, G], 2: [I, C, J, C, K, G]}
```

I'm looking for a way to create a nested dictionary, where every repeated value in the list of values for a key becomes a key of a sub-dictionary. Could you advise what approaches can I consider bearing in mind that I'm dealing with a large dataset? What I did so far has a major flaw as I loose the information on which value should be assigned to which key in sub-dictionaries.

Comment: Should "I" be in the result, or no? If not, why not?

Comment: It should! My mistake, sorry :) Every value from the original input should be included

Comment: can you exploit, that the first ordering key is at the zeroth position in each sublist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` here, but just passing `list` won't work, because you don't want a dict whose values are lists; you want a dict whose values are dicts, each of which has values that are lists. So you've got to pass a second layer of `defaultdict` to the first `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

seq = [[1, 'B', 'C'],[1, 'D', 'C'],[1, 'E', 'C'],[1, 'F', 'G'],[1, 'H', 'G'],[2, 'I', 'C'],[2, 'J', 'C'],[2, 'K', 'G']]
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for key1, value, key2 in seq:
    d[key1][key2].append(value)

print(d)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00DEC6A8>, {1: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C': ['B', 'D', 'E'], 'G': ['F', 'H']}), 2: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C': ['I', 'J'], 'G': ['K']})})
```

... Which is equivalent, item-wise, to `{1: {'C': ['B', 'D', 'E'], 'G': ['F', 'H']}, 2: {'C': ['I', 'J'], 'G': ['K']}}`

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for! What if the input also contains a list such as [1, 'B', 'D', 'C], where 'B' and 'D' should both be included as values in a sub-dictionary where 'C' is the key? (The key of a dictionary is always first, the key of a sub-dictionary is always last, and everything in between should be values of a sub-dictionary)

Comment: In that case I'd recommend changing the loop to `for key1, *values, key2 in seq: d[key1][key2].extend(values)`. Provided you're using Python 3, since [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) doesn't exist in 2.7 and lower.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion to handle input with sublists of arbitrary length:

```
import itertools
keys = [[lambda x:x[0], lambda x:x[1:]], [lambda x:x[-1], lambda x:x[:-1]]]
l = [[1, 'B', 'C'],[1, 'D', 'C'],[1, 'E', 'C'],[1, 'F', 'G'],[1, 'H', 'G'],[2, 'I', 'C'],[2, 'J', 'C'],[2, 'K', 'G']]
def group_result(d, keys):
  k, splice = keys[0]
  c = {a:[splice(i) for i in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=k), key=k)}
  return {a:group_result(b, keys[1:]) if keys[1:] else [i for c in b for i in c] for a, b in c.items()}

print(group_result(l, keys))
```

Output:

```
{1: {'C': ['B', 'D', 'E'], 'G': ['F', 'H']}, 2: {'C': ['I', 'J'], 'G': ['K']}}
```